# Mongodb: Is it a good idea to create a unique index on web URLs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, indexing, mongoid

My document looks like:

```
{"url": "http://some-random-url.com/path/to/article"
"likes": 10
}
```

The url needs to be unique. Is it a good idea to have a unique index on the `url`? The URL can be long, resulting in larger index size, more memory footprint, and slower overall performance. Is it a good idea to generate a hash from the url (i am thinking about using [murmur3](https://code.google.com/p/smhasher/wiki/MurmurHash3)) and create a unique index on that instead. I am assuming that the chances of collision are pretty low, as described here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49550/which-hashing-algorithm-is-best-for-uniqueness-and-speed

Does anyone see any drawbacks to this approach? The new document will look like (with a unique index on `u_hash` instead of `url`):

```
{"url": "http://some-random-url.com/path/to/article"
"likes": 10
"u_hash": "<murmur3 hash of url>"
}
```

**UPDATE**

I will not be doing regex queries on the `url`. Will be doing only a complete URL look up. I am more concerned about the performance of this look up, as I believe it will also be used internally by mongodb to maintain unique index, and hence affecting write performance as well (+ longer index). Additionally, my understanding is that mongobd doesn't perform well for long text indexes, as it wasn't designed for that purpose. I may be wrong though, and it could only depend on whether or not that index fits into RAM. Any pointers?

Comment: i am facing the same issue currently, were you able to figure out how to store the urls in a hashed format? my urls are 1000- 3000 characters long but unique and keep generating the index too large error,

Comment: My URLs weren't this long and I ended up creating an index on URL. If most of your URLs are > 1000 chars you might want to try text indexes: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/. Now sure how performant it is, so you'll need to try it out.

Another approach could be that you shorten your URLs before saving by implementing a shortener yourself, or using a third party one, and then index the shortened URL instead.

Comment: Did you come up with what’s best as the URL is killing my performance at the moment

Comment: The question is too old to remember, but I guess we had no issues with the index on URLs, though I think our URLs were not too long (possibly internal URLs). If you have too long URLs and the index is eating up all your memory, then you can try the URL shortener method or index the hash instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to expand on the answer of @AlexRyan. While he is right in general, there are some things which need to be taken into consideration for this use case.

First of all, we have to differentiate between a unique index and the `_id` field.

When the URL needs to be unique in your use case, there has to be a unique index. What we have to decide is wether to use the URL itself or a hashed value of it. The hashing itself would not help with the search, as the hash sum saved in a field would be treated as a string by MongoDB. It *may* safe space (URLs may be shorter than their hash value), hereby reducing the memory needed for the index. However, doing so takes away the possibility to search for parts of the URL in the index, for example with

```
db.collection.find({url:{$regex:/stackoverflow/}})
```

With a unique index on url, this query would use an index, which will be quite fast. Without such (unique) index, this query will result in a comparably slow collection scan.

Plus, creating the hash each and every time before querying, updating or inserting doesn't make these operations faster.

This leaves us with the fact that creating a hash sum and a unique index on it may save some RAM at the cost of making queries on the actual field slower at orders of magnitude. And it introduces the need of creating a hash sum each and every time. Having a index on both the URL and it's hashed value would not make sense at all.

Now to the question wether it is a good idea to use URL as `_id` one way or the other. Since URLs usually are distinct by nature (they are supposed to return the same content) and the likes are related to that uniqueness, I would tend to use the URL as the id. Since you need the unique index on `_id` anyway, it serves two purposes here: you have your id for the document, you ensure uniqueness of the URL and - in case you use the natural representation of the URL - it will even be queryable in an efficient way.

Comment: Added an update to the question. I am more concerned about the read/write performance of the full `url` lookup and addition, when compared to doing it for a hash (generation of which is pretty fast - the SO link has details about fast hashing alogos for non crytographic purposes). Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: Regardless how fast it is: hashing a value and saving it is slower than _not_ hashing and saving it. The few bytes you might save aren't exactly the problem. Disk latency is by far a bigger problem unless you have extremely long urls (a higher factor of block size, which means URLs much longer than 4kB).

Comment: Re "The hashing itself would not help with the search, as the hash sum saved in a field would be treated as a string by MongoDB": The hash is saved in the index with a reference to the corresponding documents and not on the documents. It will also help with the search just like any index, except it can only satisfy equality conditions and not range conditions as hashing does not preserve the order of values.

Comment: @wdberkely: that would be for a hashed index, right? Not for an index on a manually hashed field, or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

Use a unique index on url

```
db.interwebs.ensureIndex({ "url" : 1}, { "unique" : 1 })
```

and not a hashed index. Hashed indexes in MongoDB are meant to be used for hashed shard keys and not for unique constraints. From the [hashed index docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-hashed/),

> Hashed indexes support sharding a collection using a hashed shard key. Using a hashed shard key to shard a collection ensures a more even distribution of data.

and

> You may not create compound indexes that have hashed index fields or specify a unique constraint on a hashed index

If `url` needs to be unique and you will use it to look up documents, it's absolutely worth having a unique index on `url`. If you want to use `url` as the primary key for documents, you can store the `url` value in the `_id` field. This field is normally a driver-generated ObjectId but it can be any value you like. There's always a unique index on `_id` in a MongoDB collection so you get the unique index "for free".

Comment: I have the same problem currently, my urls are 1000-3000 characters long but 100% unique, how do I go about hashing them? does mongodb have some inbuilt mechanism to hash urls or do I need a 3rd party library? any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is "it depends".

Choosing keys that have no real world meaning embedded in them may save you pain in the future. This is especially true if you decide you need to change it but you have a lot of foreign keys referencing it.

Most database management systems offer you a way to generate unique IDs.
In Oracle, you might use a sequence.
In MySQL you might use AUTO_INCREMENT when you define the table itself.

The way that mongodb assigns unique ids to documents is different than in relational databases. They use ObjectIDs for this purpose.

One of the interesting things about ObjectIDs is that they are generated by the driver.
Because of the algorithm that is used to generate them, they are guaranteed to be unique even if you have a large cluster of app and database servers.

You can learn more about them here:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/

A lot of engineering work has gone into ensuring that ObjectIds unique.
I use them by default unless there is a really good reason not to.
So far, I have not found a really good reason to not use them.

Comment: I never questioned the usefulness or validity of mongo ids. In my particular case, the URL needs to be unique, and I need to quickly look up URLs among millions of documents. So it's centered more around whether or not should I create an index directly on url, or the hash of url.

Comment: `_id`'s don't have to be ObjectIds. They can be anything (but have to be unique for all documents on one mongod).